# How to mandate just position 0 of advanced function in PowerShell with multiple parameters

Tags: powershell

I'm in the process of turning one of my standard functions into an advanced function. The function basically talks to servers in my company and returns information I need about a product we have. currently it is coded to just scan all the servers but I want to add switches to where MyFunc -All will scan all servers, MyFunc -Single SERVERNAME will scan just that server, MyFunc -Help will display info about the function.

I have the function working to where if you are put everything in like you should it works fine. The problem I'm running into is forcing someone to input a switch at position 0 when running the function. As is if I call the function without a switch it asks for a value to be supplied for "All". If I leave the value blank or input anything I get an error message "Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'All'".

This is my first attempt at advanced functions so I'm sure I'm missing something but I figured there would be a way to require position 0 input.

Example of what I'm looking for (if possible)

PS>MyFunc

PS>"Since no switch was given we are asked to provide a switch"

PS>-All or -Help or -Single SERVERNAME

PS>Results print out

```
function MyFunc
{
   [CmdletBinding()]
   PARAM(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
      [switch]$All,
      [switch]$Help,
      [switch]$Single,
      [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
      [string]$ServerName
   )

   If($all)
   {
      $Servers = @("Server1",
             "Server2",
             "Server3",
             "Server4",
             "Server5")
              #Check servers
   }
   elseif($Single)
   {
      $Servers = @($ServerName)
              #Check server
   }
   elseif($Help)
   {
      #Print help message
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a few changes to the way you call your function and define its parameters.

First, get rid of the `-Help` switch. PowerShell has (very good) help semantics, and you should use these. Define [comment-based help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847834.aspx) for your function, and then the user can call `Get-Help MyFunc` or `help MyFunc` and see all of your function's information. The best part is, you don't have to do anything if all you want is the parameters and which ones are required; that gets generated for you automatically (go ahead and try getting help for your function now, with no changes).

Second, my recommendation would be to avoid statically defining the servers in the function (for `-All`). Just take a single `-ServerName` parameter that takes an array, and make your function check whatever is in it. It's very easy in PowerShell to make this work when accepting a single item and an array. With an advanced function this can also work on the pipeline, with minimal additional changes.

That would leave your function with a single parameter, while letting it remain just as versatile. My version of your function would look like this:

```
function MyFunc
{
   [CmdletBinding()]
   PARAM(
      [Parameter(
          ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true,
          ValueFromPipeline=$true
      )]
      [string[]]
      $ServerName
   )

   Process {
       foreach ($server in $ServerName) {
           # check this particular server
       }
   }
}
```

Here are the different ways you can call this function that all work:

```
MyFunc 'SomeServer'
MyFunc 'Server4' 'Server5' 'Server6' # Spaces
MyFunc -ServerName 'ThisServer'
MyFunc -ServerName 'ThatServer','ThisServer','OtherServer'
'CoolServer' | MyFunc
'Server1','Server2','Server3' | MyFunc
```

The caller of the function could pre-define the list of servers using [`$PSDefaultParameterValues`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847819.aspx).

If you really want to pre-define a list of servers, you could put them in a separate text file, one per line, then do something like this:

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\List\Servers.txt' | MyFunc
```

That's the beauty of supporting the pipeline in your functions!

You could also define a function that gives you the list, whose implementation could change later:

```
function Get-DefaultServerList {
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

    @(
        'Server1'
        'Server2'
        'Server3'
    )

}
```

Then you can do:

```
Get-DefaultServerList | MyFunc
```

What's the point? You can change that function's definition later to (say) get its list from a file, from a web service, from the registry, whatever.

Comment: Nicely done; may be worth mentioning that you comment-based help also gives you automatic `-?` parameter support.

Comment: That one: `MyFunc 'Server1','Server2','Server3'` will not work properly with `ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true`.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Good point; to elaborate: if you specify the remaining arguments as an _array_ (comma-separated), you _must_ use the parameter name explicitly, i.e.: `MyFunc -ServerName Server1, Server2, Server3`. Without the parameter name, only the _space_-separated form works.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [briantist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40141939/45375) with some general recommendations:

- To implement *mutually exclusive* parameters, use *parameter sets*.

  - See [`Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847743.aspx) and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878348(v=vs.85).aspx
- Don't make `[switch]` parameters *mandatory*, unless they are used to select (uniquely imply use of) *one* of the defined parameter sets.<sup>Tip of the hat to [briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist) for his help.</sup>

  - For the function *as a whole*, across all parameter sets, `[switch]`es should be *optional* (and should always default to `$False`, which they do implicitly);
    in other words: there should be at least one parameter set that does *not* require the user to pass a switch.
- Using *comment-based help* makes your advanced function automatically work not only with `Get-Help`, but also makes it support the standard `-?` parameter to invoke basic help (for more detailed help, `Get-Help` must be used).

  - See [`Get-Help about_Comment_Based_Help`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847834.aspx).
- Try to avoid `ValueFromRemainingArguments`, if possible: the PowerShell way to pass an open-ended set of related values is to use an *array* parameter instead, to which you pass the values *comma-separated*.

Based on the recommendations above, here's a rewritten form of your function.

I've changed the `-ServerName` parameter to `-ComputerName` for consistency with the standard cmdlets.

Briantist has a point about not hard-coding server names into the function, but I'm doing it here to illustrate use of parameter sets:
You *either* invoke `MyFunc` with `-All` *or* at least 1 server name.
The use of parameter sets ensures that you cannot do both.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
One-line description.

.DESCRIPTION
More detailed description

.PARAMETER All
Targets all servers.

.PARAMETER ComputerName
The name(s) of the server(s) to targets.

.EXAMPLE
> MyFunc -All
#>
function MyFunc {
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Given', PositionalBinding=$False)]
  param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Given', Position=0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string[]] $ComputerName
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='All', Mandatory)]
    [switch] $All
  )

  begin {
    # If -All was specified, determine the set of servers.
    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'All') {
      $ComputerName = 'Server1', 'Server2'
    }
  }

  process {
    foreach ($server in $ComputerName) {
      $server # process each server
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Great stuff! I agree about `[switch]` parameters never being mandatory _except_ when it comes to parameter sets. If the switch is the defining parameter of the set or basically if the switch must be present for that set to be chosen, then it's a good idea (and sometimes required) for it to be mandatory.  It's a very specific, but important exception. In your example, I would make the `-All` switch mandatory. I think that would actually preclude the need for `DefaultParameterSetName` in this case.

Comment: Also I missed your earlier comment about `-?`, that's really cool; I never knew that!

Comment: @briantist: Thanks; good point about the mandatory `[switch]`; I've restructured and amended the answer accordingly (let me know if it makes sense). You do still need `DefaultParameterSetName`, however, because without it you'd get a `Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.` error if you invoked the function _without arguments_.

Comment: Ahhh right, forgot the no arguments scenario; edits look great, awesome answer!